# c# updating progressbar and label with invoke

Tags: c#, progress-bar, invoke

I have this problem: in my form I have a progressbar and a label, my goal is to show the progress of a download and into the label the count of the bytes.
due to the fact that the values are from a backgroundworker I use this code:

```
void WebClient_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string sFormatted = string.Format("{0} of {1}", e.BytesReceived, e.TotalBytesToReceive);

    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
        myProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        myLabel.Text = sFormatted;
    }));
}
```

and this code work fine, but the progressbar is refreshed after a while, and the label is refreshed correctly:

for example: I have 10000 bytes to download, I have downloaded 5000, the label shows correctly 5000 of 10000, but the bar is like 30% not 50...

how can I solve this?

thanks in advance

Comment: As you are working with percentage, have you set the Maximum property of your progress bar to 100 ?

Comment: yes.. the values are correct, the problem is that the progressbar is refreshed slowly instead of the label...

Comment: Long time since I did this...not sure how it works; Have you tried Application.DoEvents() after assigning to the label?

Comment: yes, but doesn't change anything